# Powershell Question: Get-Command not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to view the commands that are preinstalled in the 'Poshgram' Module but every time i run 'Get-Command -Module Poshgram', I do not get any results back. I have no idea why.

I already installed the module itself. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `Get-Command Poshgram -ListAvailable | Format-List -Property Exported*` show?

Answer (score 0):

- If you indeed installed the module (in a directory listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, so that the [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules?view=powershell-7.2#module-auto-loading) feature finds it, if referenced by *name* only - verify with
  `Get-Module -ListAvailable Poshgram`),
- then the implication of `Get-Command -Module Poshgram` outputting *nothing*<sup>[1]</sup>  is that the module *cannot be (automatically) imported*.

While, as of PowerShell 7.2, `Get-Command -Module` regrettably reports no *error* in this case (and, similarly, reports no error if the specified module *isn't installed*), you can surface an error stating the reason for the inability to import the module with an explicit [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) call:

```
# This should tell you why the module cannot be imported.
Import-Module -Verbose -Force Poshgram
```

---

<sup>[1] I'm leaving aside the hypothetical that the module has *no exports*.</sup>